# Java deploy a server program

Tags: java, database, sockets, deployment

I have a Java socket server program listening on a specific port. When receiving data from GPS Trackers (TCP/IP):

1. treate data
2. insert data into a small database

I want to make this program work robustly during a long period... how ?  (web services, .. ?)

Thanks.

Comment: please add more information about your requirement- what kind of client you expect? do you going to write the client side too? are the client on the same domain or over the net (tcp/ http)? and so on...

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/ + http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish

Comment: Data is received from GPS Trackers (TCP/IP). This server doesn't respond, it only listens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a java application server like [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) maybe with with [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/).
And if data model on DB is complex you can use [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) too, to make simple storing data on db.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like [Apache Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/). This gives you some infrastructure to make sure that Java daemons can be easily started and stop and run in the background from *NIX and Windows systems.